# Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Tags: d3.js

When I am running the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Demo: GeoJSON</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/webserver/d3/d3.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* No style rules here yet */       
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Width and height
            var w = 500;
            var h = 300;

            //Define default path generator
            var path = d3.geo.path();

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            //Load in GeoJSON data
            d3.json("http://localhost/webserver/us-states.json", function(json) {

                //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
                svg.selectAll("path")
                   .data(json.features)
                   .enter()
                   .append("path")
                   .attr("d", path);

            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/webserver/us-states.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

What is going wrong here and how do I solve it?
I am following the book of Scott Murray and I didn't have problems to access files so far on my webserver until I started with json.

Comment: Found the solution myself. --disable-web-security in Chrome did the work for me.

Comment: Thats not a long term solution - better to look into CORS and sending the correct access control allow origin header

Comment: What do you mean with that imrane?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Answer (score 9):

For security reasons, browsers blocks Ajax HTTP requests (XHR) from different hosts (origins).

The `d3.json("...")` function makes an Ajax request to your http://localhost/... and you are probably serving the HTML from a different host.

**Are you opening the .html as file in the browser?** Thats considered a different host. You have some options there:

- Serve your HTML file from the same web server you are serving the json file
- Convert your .json into a .js adding something like `var mygeodata = {your json here}` to the file and adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/webserver/us-states.js"></script>` in the HTML `<head>` while also removing the `d3.json("...")` part. After that you have a global variable with your data in `mygeodata`
- Configure your web server to allow CORS.

If you are studying/prototype (by the looks of it) I would go with the second approach.

Comment: Opening the .html as file in the browser and loading files through localhost in the script was the reason I ran into this issue. Opening the html page using localhost solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Very late to the party, but for anyone still having issues, it is really easy to set up an [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) instance with NPM from the directory containing all of your files you want to server.

You would just install `http-server` globally `npm i http-server -g`, then run the `http-server` from your root directory.

Once the server is running, go to your browser and input the relative path prefixed with `localhost:[port][/path/to/file]`. Port will be printed out from the command line when you run the http-server for the first time within your repo/directory, and the relative path starts with the directory you ran the http-server. This will properly serve files to the end user, without just copy and pasting a link to the literal local.