# Unable to re-create zoomable sunburst using d3js from example

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a d3js rookie and I'm trying to learn by reproducing results from existing solutions. 
I am trying to recreate this visualization : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373 but with little success.

I created an index.html file and copy pasted code from above :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

path {
  stroke: #fff;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 700,
    radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2) - 10;

var formatNumber = d3.format(",d");

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var y = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .range([0, radius]);

var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y)); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2) + ")");

d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(partition.nodes(root))
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
      .on("click", click)
    .append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name + "\n" + formatNumber(d.value); });
});

function click(d) {
  svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .tween("scale", function() {
        var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
            yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
            yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
        return function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); };
      })
    .selectAll("path")
      .attrTween("d", function(d) { return function() { return arc(d); }; });
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

</script>
```

and then I created another file named flare.json and copy pasted the the json data into it. However when I open the index.html in a webbrowser it displays a blank page. 
Please advise me what is going wrong and how to reproduce the results.

When I tried a simpler example , I was able to make it work.
the example was from here :http://christopheviau.com/d3_tutorial/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viz"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100);    

    sampleSVG.append("circle")
        .style("stroke", "gray")
        .style("fill", "white")
        .attr("r", 40)
        .attr("cx", 50)
        .attr("cy", 50)
        .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");})
        .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");});

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using a web server?

Comment: As the data was very small I wasn't using web server. Does it matter?

Comment: Yes, it does. Look at your address bar: do you have something like `file:///C:etc...` (windows) or `localhost`?

Comment: It shows file:///home/user/Desktop/d3_tutorial/index.html

Comment: That's it, this won't work. You need a web server to use `d3.json`. If you're using mac you can try MAMP, and on windows you can try WAMP. For linux I have no idea, but it must be easy to find.

Comment: Yes, that was the mistake. I found a simpler workaround for now by directly including the json data in the script. I am trying to set up the webserver.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463364/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin