# Access to XMLHttpRequest from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS Policy?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, xmlhttprequest

I am new to javascript and web development but I am trying learn to use d3 a csv file from my desktop. My code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <script src = "https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <script>
        d3.csv("csv_file.csv", function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

However, I am getting the error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Users/Desktop/College_Finder/csv_file.csv' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
index.html:10 null
```

and I have no idea what it means or how I can fix it

Comment: I'm not sure, but a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15463364/12347169).

Answer (score 0):

You must run your code on a local server.

for example:

webstorm,phpstorm or any IDE can make local server for run